# How to start services (or targets) inside a session scope?

Tags: systemd, pam

I use systemd to start most of my processes for a desktop session: xmonad (the window manager), emacs daemon, a tmux session, etc.

Listing my users processes with `loginctl user-status` consequently only shows a handful of processes under the session:

```
  Unit: user-1000.slice
        ├─session-5.scope
        │ ├─4740 lightdm --session-child 13 16
        │ ├─5047 systemctl --user --wait start xmonad-systemd-session.target
        │ └─5497 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch xmonad-systemd-session
        └─user@1000.service
```

Almost all my processes run outside of the session below `user@1000.service`. That means running `loginctl session-status` from tmux gives:

```
Could not get properties: Caller does not belong to any known session
```

I would like to tell systemd to start certain services under a particular login session. Ideally, in my session starter script I would write:

```
exec systemctl --user --wait \
    --scope $MY_DESKTOP_SESSION start xmonad-systemd-session.target
```

However there is no `--scope` option nor would I know how to get the scope name.

I run systemd 240 on a Debian-ish (inhouse) distro with libpam-systemd and dbus-user-session.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Almost all my processes run outside of the session below user@1000.service"? I have services which display in the output of `loginctl user-status` under my *user@1000.service*, but they're literally in the output, which it doesn't sound like yours are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure systemd allows having services inside a scope that already contains processes. According to the [control group interface documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) one scope or service cannot have both processes and other scopes/services as children. (Or actually it says slices contain only services and scopes, and services and scopes contain processes. But my system doesn't seem to follow those docs as I have services inside my user@1000.service.)

You can run processes inside your session scope by having them started from something already in that session. In Gnome, commands started from Alt+F2 or from e.g. an xterm (but not a gnome-terminal, which runs as its own service) run inside the session scope. I'm not aware of any other way to get a process in a scope. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594798/how-do-i-run-a-command-in-a-different-already-existing-scope-or-session).

To me it is really obvious that you sometimes want to have a service inside of your session, (i.e. have it killed if the session is killed, have multiple copies if you have multiple sessions) so if that doesn't exist I hope it will be built some time.

Comment: To explain what's happening with user@1000.service, the user@.service template delegates cgroup controllers to the process it starts, which is a per-user instance of systemd. While the cgroup hierarchy might make it look like that, the units below the user service don't belong to the system-wide systemd, i.e. PID 1.  If you do a regular `systemctl status` on these, you will get an error because it doesn't know they exist. You have to use `systemctl --user status` to talk to your user's instance of systemd.