# How do I run a command in a different, already existing, systemd scope or session?

Tags: systemd, session

How do I run a command in a different already existing systemd session or scope?

As far as I can tell there is no difference between a session and the session's scope unit, as far as processes being in one or the other is concerned.

This question comes up because in Gnome, commands run from the terminal are seen as part of the `gnome-terminal-server.service`, not as part of the `session-xx.scope`. If I want to run a command in my session (or in another session for that matter) how do I do that?

(NB: this is the reverse of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525740/how-do-i-create-a-systemd-scope-for-an-already-existing-process-from-the-command) question, which asks to create a new scope around existing processes.)

Comment: Looking at the available methods via `busctl --user introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager`, you may have success with `AttachProcessesToUnit`. I couldn't get it to work myself, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

[@GammaFunction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/377680/gammafunction) points to the right direction, and I managed to succeed with the following command:

```bsh
$ systemd-run --user --scope --unit="app-sleep" --property=Delegate=yes sleep 9999 &
$ disown
$ sleep 8888 &
$ pid=$(jobs -p)
$ busctl --user call org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager AttachProcessesToUnit ssau "app-sleep.scope" / 1 "$pid"
```

The `ssau` (I think it means `string`, `string`, `array of unsigned`) here denotes the parameter types passed to function `AttachProcessesToUnit`, the documentation of this function can be found in `man:org.freedesktop.systemd1(5)`.

Notes:

1. The unit to be attached should set `Delegate=yes` (see `man:systemd.resource-control(5)`)
2. To pass an array of pids, you should pass the length of the array before the pids (which is 1 in the above example).

After attaching it to the given scope, you can see the scope's child processes via `systemd-cgls` or `systemctl --user status app-sleep.scope`.

Comment: Thanks for solving this puzzle and posting the solution.  I have looked *everywhere* and this is the only thing that worked.